# How to show image in ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android

I have an images in my `GridView`. Now I want to show the `image` in `ViewPager` in `next Activity`.I am trying to set a `bitmap` to that `imageView` (view) in another `class`.But after run the app image is not show in `ViewPager`.Thanks to appreciate.

Hare is code

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity
{

    private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ArrayList<String> mThumbIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Intent i = getIntent();

        mThumbIds = (ArrayList<String>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
        System.out.println("mThumbIds = " + mThumbIds);

        int  position = i.getIntExtra("id", 0);
        System.out.println("position = " + position);

        adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(this , mThumbIds);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}
```

Here is Adapter class

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements OnTouchListener{

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Button btnClose;
        Button btnEdit;
        TouchImageView imgDisplay;


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container, false);

        imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        imgDisplay.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);


        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _activity.finish();
            }
        });



        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout); 
        return viewLayout;
    }


     @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }


    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is TouchImageView code

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

        Matrix matrix;

        // We can be in one of these 3 states
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int DRAG = 1;
        static final int ZOOM = 2;
        int mode = NONE;

        // Remember some things for zooming
        PointF last = new PointF();
        PointF start = new PointF();
        float minScale = 1f;
        float maxScale = 3f;
        float[] m;

        int viewWidth, viewHeight;
        static final int CLICK = 3;
        float saveScale = 1f;
        protected float origWidth, origHeight;
        int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

        ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

        Context context;

        public TouchImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            sharedConstructing(context);
        }

        public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            sharedConstructing(context);
        }

        private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
            super.setClickable(true);
            this.context = context;
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
            matrix = new Matrix();
            m = new float[9];
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

            setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                    origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                    origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                    }

                    setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    invalidate();
                    return true; // indicate event was handled
                }

            });
        }

        public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
            maxScale = x;
        }

        private class ScaleListener extends
                ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                mode = ZOOM;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
                float origScale = saveScale;
                saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
                if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                    saveScale = maxScale;
                    mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
                } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                    saveScale = minScale;
                    mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
                }

                if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                        || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                            viewHeight / 2);
                else
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                            detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

                fixTrans();
                return true;
            }
        }

        void fixTrans() {
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

            float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
            float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                    * saveScale);

            if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
                matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
        }

        float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
            float minTrans, maxTrans;

            if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
                minTrans = 0;
                maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            } else {
                minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
                maxTrans = 0;
            }

            if (trans < minTrans)
                return -trans + minTrans;
            if (trans > maxTrans)
                return -trans + maxTrans;
            return 0;
        }

        float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
            if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
                return 0;
            }
            return delta;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            //
            // Rescales image on rotation
            //
            if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                    || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
                return;
            oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
            oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

            if (saveScale == 1) {
                // Fit to screen.
                float scale;

                Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
                if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                        || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                    return;
                int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

                Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

                float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
                float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
                scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
                matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

                // Center the image
                float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                        - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
                float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                        - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
                redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
                redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

                matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

                origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
                origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
            fixTrans();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's TouchImageView? is it your custom view? Show code in that class.

Comment: @ Seshu Vinay :- Yeah it is custom view.

Comment: @ Seshu Vinay : - I have post TouchImageView class code.

Comment: Did you debug and check if you are getting bitmap correctly in instantiateItem() method? and BTW is your XML written correctly that imageview is visible?

Comment: @Seshu Vinay :- Yeah I check it as you say and bitmap is not correctly in instantiateItem() method.It is showing null . But how to bitmap null.

Comment: So problem should be in your resizing or decoding bitmap.

Comment: By the way, resizing image is very expensive operation, don't do that in the main thread. You have to use it in a different thread and load image asynchronously.

Comment: @ Seshu Vinay :- Can you give me some code suggestion for how to work on that.

Comment: @Anjupatel hey why you not using AQuery to download and display the images???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with below code:

Remove below line of code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Add below lines:

```
aQuery.image(imgDisplay).id(_imagePaths.get(position),true,true);
```

Comment: Anju, dont forget to declate Aquery aQuery; and then in constructor, aQuery=new AQuery(activity);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load image from a path (or URL) to be displayed in an ImageView, one of the fastest and easiest way is to use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). The code is pretty short:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
     .load(path)
     .resize(width, height)
     .centerCrop()
     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: While Picasso works pretty well, I recommend using Universal Image Loader. It has many options.

Comment: Yes, that one is also a nice alternative! :)